# HTML 5 Can't Get Canvas to Work Using Webshims in IE 8 and7

Tags: html5-canvas, polyfills

I know I'm doing something incredibly stupid so was hoping a second pair of eyes can point out my folly. I'm trying to get the Webshims polyfill to work on a simple canvas test (my first dabble with it). Works great in Chrome and IE9 but testing in IE8 and IE7 (developer tools) I get the error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js-webshim/minified/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
        <script>
            // set options for html5shiv
            if(!window.html5){
                window.html5 = {}; 
            }
            window.html5.shivMethods = false;
        </script>
        <script src="js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
        <script class="example">
            window.FlashCanvasOptions = {
                disableContextMenu: true
            };
            $.webshims.setOptions({

                waitReady: false
            });

            $.webshims.polyfill();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="my-canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
        </canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = $('#my-canvas').getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
            ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
            ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);

            window.FlashCanvasOptions = {disableContextMenu: true};
            $.webshims.setOptions('canvas', {type: 'excanvas'});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I wrap the canvas code in a jquery ready function I don't get an error, but I don't get the canvas rendered either.

```
$(function(){
    var ctx = $('#my-canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
    ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
    ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
});
```

I've tested it in BrowserStack with the same results. What am I doing wrong? I'm happy to have my dimness exposed for all to see..!

Comment: I tried that - see by second code snippet. I didn't get an error but didn't get the canvas to render either. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but perhaps this will help someone.

I was having this exact same error - no errors logged, but nothing was appearing on the canvas either.

This was fixed by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Comment: I can't remember what I did but got it working. It was a while ago! But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove waitReady or set it to true.